# Update spring Model value from javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring mvc, javascript, jquery, ajax and HTML with Thymeleaf and I pass value from controller to HTML page through `Model`.
Using `Model` I add the supplied attribute under the supplied name.

```
model.addAttribute("carTypeList",fleetAndCarService.getCarsType());
```

I use this value in a form with select tag.
In HTML code I have:

```
<form id="addCarForm" role="form" action="#" th:action="@{/fleetAndCar/car}" th:object="${carForm}" method="post">
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Fleet application</label>
                <!-- Show fleet application -->
                <input class="form-control" type="text"
                    th:value="${fleetApplication.application}"
                    readonly="readonly" />
                <!-- Save into fleet the value of idFleet -->
                <input type="hidden" name="fleet"
                    th:value="${fleetApplication.idFleet}" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="radio">
                <label> <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios"
                    onclick="existingCar();" checked> Use existing car
                    type
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label> <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios"
                    onclick="newCar();"> Create new car type
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id=existingCarType>
            <label>CarType</label> <select class="form-control select2"
                style="width: 100%;" th:field="*{carType}">
                <option th:each="carType: ${carTypeList}"
                    th:value="${carType.idCarType}"
                    th:text="${carType.idCarType}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id=newCarType style="display: none;">
            <label>CarType</label> <input id=carTypeText
                th:field="*{carType}" type="text" class="form-control"
                placeholder="New car Type" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But in this form page user can select or add one carsType so the next time that he views all the carsType he doesn't find the last created until he doens't refresh the page.
Is there a way to update this model value from javascript, HTML or other way to obtain the updated value?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .change() method. https://api.jquery.com/change/

This event listener will run every time the user changes the select box.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/robbroden/m8doezdq/

HTML

```
<select id="selectElement">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
var value;

$('#selectElement').change(function(){
    value = $('#selectElement').val();
    alert(value);
});
```